# Powershell to view last login date for users?

Tags: 2010, 2013, powershell

I tried Googling this, but had no success. Is there a PowerShell script, or would it be possible to write one to show the last login date of each user into the SharePoint environment?

Comment: I wonder if you're able to see users informations, and you see their last login, you'll be able to write a script for that. Check the `Get-SPUser` maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say no.

But you can find the information when the user was last logon to the domain using this script:

```
# Load the SharePoint cmdlets
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'} 
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{    
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"    
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"  -EA SilentlyContinue
}

# Import ActiveDirectory cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Here's the function that will return the last logon date and time
function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName)
{
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $time = 0
  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  { 
    $hostname = $dc.HostName
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
    {
      $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
  }
  $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
  Write-Host $username "last logged on at:" $dt 
}

# Get the user profiles
$site=Get-SPSite "https://intranet.company.com/"
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context) 
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

# Iterate all profiles and grab the users last logon date time and write to comsole
foreach($user in $profiles)
{
     Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $user["UserName"]
}
```

And you'll get the following output:

```
SP2010Dev last logged on at: 08/08/2013 09:02:16
SP2010UPS last logged on at: 08/08/2013 01:00:10
SP2010Search last logged on at: 02/08/2013 23:55:42
SP2010Setup last logged on at: 01/01/1601 01:00:00
SP2010Crawl last logged on at: 08/08/2013 00:04:51
SP2010Farm last logged on at: 08/08/2013 06:11:01
Administrator last logged on at: 10/02/2011 14:04:13
SP2010App last logged on at: 05/08/2013 18:55:43
SP2010SqlSvc last logged on at: 05/08/2013 12:10:29
testtwo last logged on at: 18/03/2013 15:38:43
test6 last logged on at: 20/06/2013 11:35:04
test4 last logged on at: 13/06/2013 13:10:39
```

Reference on calling Active Directory: [Determining a User's Last Logon Time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378867%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

That information (last login time) is not stored or managed by SharePoint at all...

Answer (score 2):

You can read IIS log files using C# and determine last login of the current user. Below article shows you how to read IIS log files using C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13504/Simple-log-parsing-using-MS-Log-Parser-2-2-in-C-NE