# How we can find Users who have accessed SharePoint 2010 subsite

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, web-analytics, site-usage, usage-counters

How we can find users who have accessed SharePoint 2010 subsite by using web analytics service.

Top Visitor reports contain lot of repetition of user accounts like domain\user1 and User1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Auditing Reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131) - Content viewing to do the trick.

PowerShell cannot query last access date or user access, you can try to use IIS logs.

Here are some references.

[Getting last accessed date of sitecollection/sites.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221102/getting-last-accessed-date-of-sitecollection-sites)

[last access date/time for sharepoint site collections.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/228574cd-8c68-4f20-bd43-9025b1730656/last-access-datetime-for-sharepoint-site-collections?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: Thank you Chelsea, sure I'll give it a try